# Python - Criteria based selection on netCDF files

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netCDF file `test.nc`, having the following variables included:

- `time`
- `lat`
- `lon`
- `Lai_500m`
- `FparLai_QC`

all variables (except `time`, `lat`, `lon`) have a 1523, 120, 120 shape.

Now I would like to select only the data which has been labeled has high quality in the `FparLai_QC` and the data having `Lai_500m`<20.

In order to do so I have tried:

```
os.chdir(inbasedir)
data = xr.open_dataset('MCD15A3H.006_500m_aid0001.nc')
qc_data = data.loc[(dict(var='Lai_500m') < 20) &
                  (dict(var='FparLai_QC') == 0) ]
```

and:

```
os.chdir(inbasedir)
data = xr.open_dataset('MCD15A3H.006_500m_aid0001.nc')
qc_data = data.loc[(data['Lai_500m'] < 20) &
                  (data['FparLai_QC'] == 0) ]
```

Both of them returned the same error:

```
TypeError: can only lookup dictionaries from Dataset.loc
```

Does anyone knows how to achieve my data selection?

Comment: I think this use of .loc with xarray is limited to selecting based on the dimension variables (time, lat, lon).
One option could be to look at nco tools. See the end of Section 4.14.2 in the documentation for filtering/masking based on variable values.
http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#Normalization-and-Integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xarray's [`where` method](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html#xarray.DataArray.where) is good for this sort of operation:

```
qc_data = data.where((data['Lai_500m'] < 20) & (data['FparLai_QC'] == 0))
```

You may also find the `drop` keyword useful if you want to drop coordinate labels that only correspond to False values of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use where in this case. If you use Xarray to read your netcdf file I would rather use [sel](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sel.html) (filtering per value) or [isel](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.isel.html) (filtering per index).

i.e

```
import xarray as xr
    with xr.open_dataset(
            filename_or_obj='file_name.nc',
            engine='netcdf4') as file:
        WIND = file.WIND.sel(Lai_500m=20,
                             FparLai_QC=0).sel(
            time=start_date, method='nearest')
```